# Google App Script Add-On and Google Analytics Tracking

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I am trying to track events in my google app script add-on (Working with Cards `"runtimeVersion": "V8",`), but unfortunately, the urls I am creating to post to GA are not making any impact on my google-analytics dashboard, checking the realtime monitor. But ... when I call the URLs in the browser address-bar, I am getting events tracked.

This is what my URL looks like:

`https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=*****&cid=APrZferAeSHwd9C/aYIQPlcTig1FoMOG6Q/9zD+W9EcG62NnYQgGpB0tfXd7TheppU1CwdObIjrr&t=event&aip=false&ds=google%20addOn&ec=trigger&ea=triggered&el=homepageTrigger&ev=1`

And this is what I try to do in the GAS:

```js
let options: object = {
    method: 'POST',
    payload: googleTrackEvent.toUrlParameterString(),
};

// @ts-ignore
console.log("https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect" + "?" + options.payload);

let responseCode: any = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect', options).getResponseCode();
if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode > 299){
    console.error({call: 'GATrack', error:responseCode});
} else {
    console.log(responseCode);
}
```

So the URL is taken from the `console.log` debug output under the ts-ignore line.
As said, this url copied to a browser address-bar creates an event.

And the response from the URL is `200`.

I also set the permission in the `appscript.json`

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably recognized as a bot / spam. Try to add other parameters to the call such as the host name (`dh`) and the pagePath (`dp`) or the location (`dl`) or even `ua` parameter: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ua

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'll try that out. Is there a way to find that out, specifically? Any "blacklist" or something i could test against?

Comment: No, it is not a question of blacklisting but of hits with incomplete parameters that are recognized as bots. Let me know!

Comment: I tryed that now, but ... I don't get the user Agent information in GAS: `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined` nor the `location.` properties ... how would I access those data?

Comment: what is your experience with google app script and tracking events? can you share some information, how you got it running?

Comment: You can get the agent with: `HtmlService.getUserAgent()`